# How to check if request is ajax or not in codebehind - ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, webforms

I tried the `Request.IsAjaxRequest` but this does not exist in WebForms. I am making a JQuery ajax call. How do I check if this is a ajax request or not in C#?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You could create your own extension method much like the one in the [MVC code](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/60098#338547)

E.g.

```
public static bool IsAjaxRequest(this HttpRequest request)
{
    if (request == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
    }

    return (request["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest") || ((request.Headers != null) && (request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest"));
}
```

HTHs,
Charles

**Edit:** Actually Callback requests are also ajax requests,

```
    public static bool IsAjaxRequest(this HttpRequest request)
    {
        if (request == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
        }
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        var isCallbackRequest = false;// callback requests are ajax requests
        if (context != null && context.CurrentHandler != null && context.CurrentHandler is System.Web.UI.Page)
        {
            isCallbackRequest = ((System.Web.UI.Page)context.CurrentHandler).IsCallback;
        }
        return isCallbackRequest || (request["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest") || (request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest");
    }
```

Comment: That last line can be refactored to `return request["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest" || request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest";`

Comment: added is callback support

Answer (score 5):

Try to check if the ScriptManager [IsInAsyncPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.isinasyncpostback.aspx) :

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).IsInAsyncPostBack
```

Comment: Does this work for ajax requests that are triggered both from jquery ajax as well as from controls such as Update panels?

Comment: I'm not sure, therefore i wrote `try`;-)

Answer (score 4):

Generally, you will need to test for the `X-Requested-With` header, ensuring that its value is 'XMLHttpRequest'. I'm not a C# developer (yet), but a quick google search says that in C# it goes something like this:

```
Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest";
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  `Request.IsAjaxRequest` looks at the headers and the querystring for `X-Requested-With`, but it seems your jquery isn't sending the `X-Requested-With` header.

You can try and see what headers it is sending by using Fiddler, or alternatively just send it in the querystring by setting the POST url to

`/whatever.aspx?x-requested-with=XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: JQuery is sending the X-Requested-With so if I check the headers per Karim79, it works. But there Request does not have a IsAjaxRequest property in the base page.

Comment: Ah, I see - i thought you meant it was always false.  What version of ASP.net are you using, and could we all see some code to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I created an extension that I use:

```
internal static bool IsAjaxRequest(this HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    return request != null && request.Headers.Any(h => h.Key.Equals("X-Requested-With", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) &&
        h.Value.Any(v => v.Equals("XMLHttpRequest", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Decorate your class with `[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]`syntax like if you write the following function in code behind and call the same function from ajax call you will be sure.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static void   getData(string JSONFirstData,string JSONSecondData, string JSONThirdData, string JSONForthData, ...)
    {
       //code
    }
```

in Ajax URL be like `URL :'/Codebehind.aspx/getData'`