# How to validate jQuery AJAX call ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery, httphandler

I have a web application where I have used http-handlers and jQuery for AJAX call.
Now the problem is user can type the same URL in the browser which is generated by the jQuery and operation is being performed.
Can I send some token with the query string and then on server side I can look for the right token before performing any operation.

Hope that I have written my problem correctly.

Comment: Do you authentication for your website ? If yes, then http handler would be invoked untill and unless the user is authenticated.

Comment: Inside the function, which you are calling in ajax call check for the login session. So now even though user will directly use the url it will validate whether the user logged in or not.

Comment: I have used form authentication and my handler are implementing IRequiresSessionState.

Comment: my problem is that after log in user can call the handler from the browser another tab. How can I avoid that.

Comment: can I implement captcha like think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The above technique is called**

> Cross Site Request Forgery

**Risk Impact**

> An attacker can hijack logged in users session for performing malicious transactions.

**Recommendations**

> It is recommended implementing Page token (a random token as an additional parameter in the request) for all transaction pages. This token should be randomly generated and should be unique for each user.

The suggested URL are

http://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRF_Guard 
http://www.cgisecurity.com/csrf-faq.html

```
var cg = new CSRFGuard(); 
cg.SetupCSRFTokenNameAndValue(); 
SessionManager.CustomerConfig.CsrfTokenName = cg.CsrfTokenName; 
SessionManager.CustomerConfig.CsrfTokenValue = cg.CsrfTokenValue;
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to handle this in a similar fashion to how it can be handled in the MVC framework.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392836/how-to-check-if-request-is-ajax-or-not-in-codebehind-asp-net-webforms) is a similar post that describes a potential solution.