# asp filter ajax and usual request

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have asp webpage in Net4.0. In this version I can't use async method. I have  ajax container:UpdatePanel . I have button in this panel. When I press button the page doesn't reload and in debug mode I see Page load method. I need filter ajax request and usual. How can I this do?

Like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(request.isAsync)
  {
    //this is ajax
  }else
  {
     //this is usual request.
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use extension method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392836/how-to-check-if-request-is-ajax-or-not-in-codebehind-asp-net-webforms)

```
public static bool IsAjaxRequest(this HttpRequest request)
{
    if (request == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
    }

    return (request["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest") || ((request.Headers != null) && (request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest"));
}
```

and make it:

```
if(request.IsAjaxRequest())
```