# What to do when writting an error log causes an error?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, logging

simple question:
What to do when the method, that should log an error, causes an error?

**Background:**
After changing a small thing on the database, that is really very hard related to the logging-system (Log-Table that get's filled when an error happens in code / from user, whatever), my code doesn't run any more.
The curios thing here was, because of the error in the database-method, the system interrupts some loading methods and jquery doesn't load, so I got JQuery errors! It took me around 5 hours to find out, that not jquery was the problem, instead it was a problem in the logging method which stops jquery to load.

So, how to avoid such things in code?

Comment: Use try catch around the logging method and use different notification when your logging method cause an exception.

Comment: It was! (not my project, I just had to change something) but in the catch () nothing happens so you cant really see if there is an error, if u have a empty catch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cater for every circumstance, and if it's not writing to the database table that should be an indication that there is a problem with the logging. If you want to step it up, you could consider writing to a text file when a DB Exception is encountered in a specific try catch.

```
try 
{
}
catch(SqlException ex)
{
  fallBackWriteErrorToTxt(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check weather a request is `ajax` or simple using following code

```
public static bool IsAjaxRequest(this HttpRequest request)
{
    if (request == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
    }
    return (request["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest") 
           || ((request.Headers != null) && 
           (request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest"));
 }
```

Using the above fiction you can find out weather a request is ajax or not.
Source: [How to check if request is ajax or not in codebehind - ASP.NET Webforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392836/how-to-check-if-request-is-ajax-or-not-in-codebehind-asp-net-webforms)

You can also create a column in database for showing which type of error has offered an pass the values form front end.

You can also use `Application_Error` method of Global file to log the error.