# How to prevent AJAX polling keeping Asp.Net sessions alive

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, session, cookies

We have a ASP.Net application that has been given a 20 minute sliding expiry for the session (and cookie).
However, we have some AJAX that is polling the server for new information. The downside of this of course is that the session will continue indefinitely, as it is being kept alive by the polling calls causing the expiry time to be refreshed. Is there a way of preventing this - i.e. to only allow the session to be refreshed on non-ajax calls?

Turning off sliding expiry is not really an option as this is an application that business users will be using for most of their day between telephone calls.

Other Stackoverflow discussions on this talk about maintaining 2 separate application (one for authenticated calls, one for unauthenticated. I'm not sure this will be an option as all calls need to be authenticated.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look on this - http://seejoelprogram.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/maintaining-aspnet-session-state-in-an-ajax-application/

Comment: +1! Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4392836/304683) offer some ideas?

Comment: You could try to disable the session state for the request: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/201879/Few-important-tips-that-you-should-know-while-usin

Comment: Just to clarify - what we are seeking to achieve is to allow the session to expire after 20 minutes if the user hasn't interacted with the page - i.e. for the session to NOT be kept alive due to ajax polling.

Comment: you can try this solution, add the session timeout and the log in time into your local storage, and at head of javascript check if the user exceed the timeout or not

Answer (score 1):

add below code to your controller action that you are reference for polling.Convert this into an attribute so it can be used everywhere. This line will not extend session timeout

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Run()
    {
        Response.Cookies.Remove(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);

        return Json("");
    }
```

Comment: This will cause user logoff and will need to login again right? That is what the question wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

As this question is old I am assuming it has been resolved or a workaround implemented. However, I wanted to mention that instead of AJAX polling the server to perform an operation we have utilized SignalR which allows both the client to communicate with the server via JQuery and/or the server to notify the client.

Check it out: [Learn About ASP.NET SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to stop the ajax from keeping the session and cookies alive!

However, there is a way to achieve what you want to do. That is if the process I will describe will be ok to you.

I think what you really want to achieve is first to refresh your page with ajax so that some processes will be active and running. Also to know when the user has stopped operating the program.

If that is what you want then there is a simple process to achieve this

1. You will have your ajax running for the things you want to run.
2. You will remove the session you want to check if user has stopped operation on the page and manage the session as a variable instead.
3. The variable can be a global variable or a class variable that will be set to initial value whenever the user clicks an element on the page.
   (You will select the click event of an element and set the variable to initial value)
4. You will increment the variable every given time (say every time your ajax runs)
5. You will also have a function/method run to check the value of that variable if it is greater than the value you set as limit. This can run every time your ajax runs or every time you want it to run (timed event).
6. If the value of your variable is greater than the limit set it should invalidate or clear session/log user out.

This way if user stops operating (clicking elements) the system on any page that this is running will eventually log out the current user and stop running the program.

Answer (score -1):

I have done this by creating a hidden page in an i-Frame. Then using JavaScript it posts back every 18 minutes to keep the session alive. This works really well.

This example is from a ASP.NET Forms project but could be tweaked for MVC.

1. Create a page called KeepSessionAlive page and add a meta refresh tag

   meta id="MetaRefresh" http-equiv="refresh" content="21600;url=KeepSessionAlive.aspx"
2. In the code behind

   protected string WindowStatusText = "";

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       //string RefreshValue = Convert.ToString((Session.Timeout * 60) - 60);

       string RefreshValue = Convert.ToString((Session.Timeout * 60) - 90);

       // Refresh this page 60 seconds before session timeout, effectively resetting the session timeout counter.
       MetaRefresh.Attributes["content"] = RefreshValue + ";url=KeepSessionAlive.aspx?q=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks;

       WindowStatusText = "Last refresh " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
   }
   ```
3. Add the hidden iFrame in a master page

   iframe ID="KeepAliveFrame" src="KeepSessionAlive.aspx" frameBorder="0" width="0" height="0"

[Download example](http://snippets.surfthru.com/post/Stop-ASPNET-Session-Timeouts)

Comment: Isn't this just the opposite of what was asked? =)

Comment: I thought so at first but the last part of the question was "... Is there a way of preventing this - i.e. to only allow the session to be refreshed on non-ajax calls?"

Comment: Yes it is the opposite - thanks artokai. See my comment above.